# Is there a C++ equivalent to Rust's `std::mem::drop` in the standard library?

Tags: c++, rust, destructor, move-semantics, lifetime

The function [`std::mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) in Rust moves its argument and then destroys it by going out of scope. My attempt at writing a similar function in C++ looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<T &&>::value>>
void drop(T &&x) {
    T(std::move(x));
}
```

Does such a function already exist in the standard library?

**Edit:** The function can be used to invoke the destructor of an object before going out of scope. Consider a class that closes a file handle as soon as it is destroyed, but not earlier. For the sake of the argument, suppose `ofstream` did not have a `close` method. You can write:

```cpp
ofstream f("out");
f << "first\n";
drop(move(f));
// f is closed now, and everything is flushed to disk
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would need something like this in C++. What is your usecase for this?

Comment: There’s nothing you can call to make a given variable invalid to use after that call as far as I know. Is it possible for you to just use blocks instead? `{ T x; } /* x is out of scope */`

Comment: When learning a new language sometimes you have to use different idioms.  I can't see a case where `drop` would be anything like idiomatic C++.  I honestly cannot think of a single reason why you'd want it.

Comment: I think the idomatic C++ way to handle this is to return from the function. If you can't return from the function, your functions are doing too much.

Comment: @CrazyEddie you've never wanted to run a destructor before the end of the scope?

Comment: @Shepmaster - No.  I've not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C++'s standard library has no such function. However, you can accomplish the same effect with this idiom:

```
SomeType var = ...;
//do stuff with `var`.
{auto _ = std::move(var);}
//The contents of `var` have been destroyed.
```

As pointed out in the comments, C++ lacks Rust's ability to actually *prevent* you from further using `var`. Its contents have been moved from, but in C++ it is still a live, valid object, and you could even reuse it by properly transitioning it to a well-defined state.

Of course, this requires that the type is move-constructible. Some types like `lock_guard` are not, so you're kinda hosed there. That means the only way to close it early is to use its built-in interface.

Comment: ``//`var` has been destroyed.`` Not really, you can still assign to it for example. Also, I still don't what this is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Were one so inclined, could you make a function that has the same effect?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: It accomplishes the destruction of whatever `var` managed. If it was a file, the file is closed. If it was a shared pointer, the reference count has decreased.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Nicol Bolas said this in the now-deleted sibling answer: *The point of the idea is that you have a stack variable that is still in scope, but you're finished using it and want the object cleaned up. Like an ifstream or something, where the destructor closes the file. You don't want to keep it open longer than needed, but it's silly to heap-allocate it just to be able to reset it.*

Comment: So why not just put the variable in the proper scope to begin with?

Comment: @Shepmaster: "*Were one so inclined, could you make a function that has the same effect?*" You could, but why? The name would have to be less than 11 characters in order to be shorter than this. `std::drop()` is 11 characters, so it wouldn't be any shorter. A function call would still need you to invoke `std::move()`, so those characters would have to remain.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Because maybe there's some other variable that you read into from the file, and that needs to be kept alive. You could refactor it into a function or something, or you could keep all of your code in a consistent place.

Comment: Not terribly convinced about the actual usefulness of this yet, but it answers the question I guess. (If I understood that `drop` thing correctly that is.)

Comment: @NicolBolas It does not accomplish the `destruction` of var though, it still needs to be in some defined state and in fact its `destructor` is never called. So for most resource management purposes, those will generally offer a more expressive alternative such as [`std::unique_ptr::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) or similar.

Comment: @HeroicKatora: `reset` doesn't call the `unique_ptr`'s destructor *either*. So I don't understand how that's an improvement. In both cases, the result of the construct is the destruction of the containing object. It's just that, in the case I outline, it works for every type that is move-constructible. Your way requires looking through the documentation for the right function (in `ifstream`, it's called `close`, not `reset`).

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess to some level I was wondering if you can have "default" move semantics on a function's arguments. In your 11 characters, you aren't including the `{auto _` and `}`, right? Those aren't needed in Rust's `drop`. There's always the possibility of the preprocessor (or probably template voodoo, which I know not about) being used to reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: @Shepmaster: "*I guess to some level I was wondering if you can have "default" move semantics on a function's arguments.*" No, you cannot. The standard was explicitly defined to *prevent* that. The 11 characters in question are the `{auto _ = }` characters. A function call would look like `std::drop()`. Both forms need `std::move()`, and both forms need a semicolon.

Comment: @NicolBolas Exactly, it does not call the destructor but at least it is expressive about it in c++ terms and makes it clear that is in fact still a valid object. Whereas rusts `std::drop` is meant for a variable which you will not use after in the scope, since there are no borrows in C++, you simply can not express the same effect.

Comment: @HeroicKatora: I have no idea how what I did doesn't make it clear that `var` is still a valid object. I see a variable definition, initialized by a move from `var`. That clearly means `var` exists and is in the moved-from state. I don't know how it could possibly be clearer.

Comment: @NicolBolas My problem is that in Rust, the effect of `std::drop` is not merely a runtime one but also a compile time one as the compiler will explicitly error if you were to still use the variable. In C++ the same thing will not happen but by porting the idiom you give an illusion of having the same comfort. In my eyes, this is clearly misleading and likely to be misused, especially regarding that OP has a Rust background.

Comment: @HeroicKatora: I've added a notation to that effect.

Comment: Why would both forms would need `std::move`? (referring to your response to Shepmaster) The `std::move` would be inside the implementation of `drop`. On the caller's side, it would just be `std::drop(var);`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: OK, if you want to move from a non-const lvalue reference, yes, you could do it that way. But it is generally considered bad form in C++ to move from a parameter in such a way.

Comment: I would think that the function's name would make it an exception to that rule.